# What is the C++ equivalent to 'r' prefix with strings in Python?

Tags: python, c++

In python, I can so the next valid code:

```
r"path\path.exe"
```

This allowed me use one slash('\') sign instead of two.
Is there any equivalent in cpp?

Comment: Almost [the same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) merely?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closest equivalent is a [**raw string literal**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
 R"x(path\path.exe)x"
```

Comment: You can remove the "x"

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is [`R "delimiter( raw_characters )delimiter"`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

`delimiter` can be (almost) anything you want (even empty), for example:

```
R"REGEX(\n.+)REGEX"
```

Answer (score 4):

E.g.

```
R"duh(path\path.exe)duh"
```

This is called a **raw string literal**, hence the `R` prefix.

General syntax

> prefix<sub>*optional*</sub> **`R`** **`"`** delimiter **`(`** raw_characters **`)`** delimiter **`"`**

The delimiter at the start, which can be empty, nothing, must be the same as the one at the end.

The optional prefix can be one of **`L`**, **`u8`**, **`u`** and **`U`**, for respectively `wchar_t`, UTF-8 encoded `char`, UTF-16 encoded `char16_t` and UTF-32 encoded `char32_t`.

See (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

Answer (score 3):

C++11 introduced raw string literals. Make sure your compiler supports C++11. Use them with a capital R, like this:

```
R"(path\path.exe)"
```

Comment: @StoryTeller: C++ support for raw string literals first appeared in C++11.